# For Each loop every Nth row and include the last row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a `For Each` loop that skips to every 200 rows and copies the data from that row to another sheet. This loop works, but I want it to include the last used row.

For example, I have 2,132 rows, so I begin my loop at the 200th row, then the 400th, and so on. The loop will go until row 2,000, and then ends since row 2,200 does not exist. However, I want to always include the last row if it isn't already included in the final loop to 200. So in this case, row 2,000 and then row 2,132.

My current loop:

```
Sub SelectEveryNthCell()
Dim rRange As Long, rEveryNth As String, lRow As Long, nRow As Long

With Sheets("Vendor Num")
     rRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 200 To rRange Step 200
        If lRow > rRange Then
            rEveryNth = .Range("B" & lRow).Value
                With Sheets("Vendor Num Chart")
                nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & nRow).Value = rEveryNth
                End With
            Exit For
        End If

        rEveryNth = .Range("B" & lRow).Value

        With Sheets("Vendor Num Chart")
            nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & nRow).Value = rEveryNth
        End With

    Next lRow

End With

End Sub
```

I thought I could capture it with the `If lRow > rRange Then` but the loop skips this and ends right after the loop when `lRow` equals 2,000.

I've seen a lot on SO about looping to the Nth, but no mention of including the last row. Is there a way to include it in the loop? I would like to avoid capturing the last row after the loop is complete, just on the off chance that the last row is the next 200th row. In that case, I would capture the row twice, which I do not want. Ex: last row is 2,000. Loop captures 2,000th row, and then after the loop captures the last row, 2,000, again.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just add `.Cells(2132, [column]).Value = [whatever]` after the `Next lRow` line?  I know you said you didn't want to capture it twice, but is there a reason? I'd think adding one line like this wouldn't really slow the macro down any.

Comment: @BruceWayne It wasn't so much about slowing it down, as it was that doing this loop is prepping for  a later task, and I wouldn't want to do the later task twice. I suppose if I added that line then I would need to do a check for duplicates and remove one of the duplicates. Not awful, but I felt there could be a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectEveryNthCell()
    Dim rRange As Long, rEveryNth As String, lRow As Long, nRow As Long

    With Sheets("Vendor Num")
        rRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For lRow = 200 To rRange Step 200
            rEveryNth = .Range("B" & lRow).Value
            With Sheets("Vendor Num Chart")
                nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & nRow).Value = rEveryNth
            End With
        Next lRow

        If rRange Mod 200 <> 0 Then
            With Sheets("Vendor Num Chart")
                nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & nRow).Value = Sheets("Vendor Num").Range("B" & rRange).Value
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This accomplishes the task also, but I'm going with Tim's answer just because it is being captured in the `For` loop. Appreciate the advice!

Comment: Are you sure the accepted answer does what my code does? Becuase when I ran that code on my set of data, `460` was ignored...

Comment: I don't see why it would be ignored. At `lRow = 400`, `If lRow > rRange - 200` would equal to `400 > 460 - 200` which is true..

Comment: Try it yourself :)

Comment: I'm too busy with my own project now :))

Comment: Then I leave the decision with you. I know because I tested that code on my data.. but anyways I will leave the decision in your hands :)

Comment: Ugh you got my interest. I can't fathom why that code would not work.. Let's see

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I double-checked with my 2,000+ rows and saw the ignored. I did not think of incorporating the `Mod` line at all. Thank you!

Comment: I still don't understand. Code tested with 460 rows as well and works just as intended

Comment: @TimStack: Tim, Type 1 to 460 in cell `B1:B460` and then try any of your code. It will onlu copy 200 and 400 :)

Comment: I have, albeit in col A. I have results in 200, 400, and 460

Comment: Is your data in Col B of "Vendor Num" @TimStack

Comment: I used my existing data, but I did see that row 2,132 was not captured, the last captured was 2,000. I won't pretend to understand why, but I can confirm what @SiddharthRout stated was also true for me.

Comment: I'll simplify my code to just the correct loop. I think OP's code is meddling with my line. Didn't check OP's code

Comment: I tried your new code @TimStack It still doesn't capture it. Note that in my case the data is in Col B of Sheet "Vendor Num"

Comment: Edited @SiddharthRout. I had misunderstood the expected output so for me it was working perfectly.. for the wrong output ;)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ways of going about to do this, but this is one

```
Sub SelectEveryNthCell()
Dim rRange As Long, rEveryNth As String, lRow As Long, nRow As Long

With Sheets("Vendor Num")
    rRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 200 To rRange Step 200
        rEveryNth = .Range("B" & lRow).Value

        With Sheets("Vendor Num Chart")
            nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & nRow).Value = rEveryNth
            If lRow > rRange - 200 Then
                nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & nRow).Value = rRange
            End If
        End With

    Next lRow

End With

End Sub
```

Another way would be outside of the loop:

```
Sub SelectEveryNthCell()
Dim rRange As Long, rEveryNth As String, lRow As Long, nRow As Long
Dim lRowChanged As Boolean

With Sheets("Vendor Num")
    rRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 200 To rRange Step 200
        If lRow = rRange Then LRowChanged = True
        rEveryNth = .Range("B" & lRow).Value

        With Sheets("Vendor Num Chart")
            nRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & nRow).Value = rEveryNth
        End With

    Next lRow

    If LRowChanged = False Then Sheets("Vendor Num Chart").Range("A" & nRow + 1).Value = .Range("B" & rRange).Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: All this (your second code) needs is `If lRowChanged = False Then Sheets("Vendor Num Chart").Range("A" & nRow + 1).Value = .Range("B" & rRange).Value` to work

Comment: @SiddharthRout That took the last few minutes of my working day. Time to celebrate the weekend

Comment: You too! See ya around